# 'De-pivoting' a matrix in matlab/octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

I want to convert a matrix M into "tall-skinny" format. The resulting matrix would have rows like [r, c, M(r,c)] for every r and c in the rows and columns of M. Is there a function which does this? Alternatively, is there a function which does the reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:size(M,1), 1:size(M,2));
T = [ii(:) jj(:) M(:)];
```

Reverse:

```
M = full(sparse(T(:,1), T(:,2), T(:,3)));
```

or more simply, as noted by Jumppy89,

```
M = full(spconvert(T));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I looked into the sparse function, turns out the reverse can be done as `M = full(spconvert(T));`

Comment: True! I didn't remember `spconvert`.  I'll include that in the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am curious too if this would satisfy your needs -

Normal to Tall-skinny (based on `meshgrid`) -

```
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(1:size(M,1),1:size(M,2))
TSM = [x2(:) x1(:) M(:)] %// Tall-Skinny M
```

Tall-skinny to Normal (based on `sub2ind` and reshaping) -

```
m1 = max(TSM(:,2))
n1 = max(TSM(:,1))
TSM3 = TSM(:,3)
M_out = reshape(TSM3(sub2ind([n1 m1],TSM(:,1),TSM(:,2))),m1,n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a different  way to Luis and Divakar, using `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` for the reverse. I doubt this is a better solution than theirs though.

To convert to the "tall-skinny" format:

```
M = [1     1     1
     1     2     2
     2     1     3
     2     2     4]
S=zeros([max(M(:,1)) max(M(:,2))])
I=sub2ind([max(M(:,1)) max(M(:,2))],M(:,1),M(:,2))
S(I)=M(:,3)
```

And the reverse:

```
[r,c]=ind2sub(size(S),1:numel(S))
M=[r.' c.' S(:)]
```